# Will my team and I be able to work on a project in Android Studio without internet connection?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, internet-connection

A group of people (me included) just got hired to work on an Android Project. However, they company said that there might be some classified information added to this project in the future, so they want us to develop everything with no internet connection (to ensure we are not sending data our, and things like that).

We will be working on different parts of the project, and supposedly upload everything to gitHub and have a build at the end of the day. Now I am not even sure how we will do that if we can't access the internet.

My question then is, will we be able to work on an entire project without accessing the internet? Won't Gradle have problem with dependencies? Android Studio and Android SDK Updates, Builds, Idk... In other words, how not having access to the internet can make this project fail?

Thanks!

Comment: More importantly, you wont be able to use SO.

Comment: Honest advice-  find employers who aren't paranoid.  Unless they're paying you so much money you'll never have to work again it isn't worth it.

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow.

Comment: Mandating total disconnection from the Internet does not seem like a reasonable way to stop dissemination of classified information. It's not like they could stop you from distributing the stuff once they give it to you, either way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why your computers have to access the internet for Android development after the inception of the project.  You just have to be sure that they are fully setup prior to start up.

But, how can you use github if you don't have internet?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need a number of things from the internet to set up the dev environment (IDE, SDKs, etc).

A local network will be needed for version control, unless you plan on doing all of the work on one machine.

I generally look up documentation online, and you probably do, too. Be sure to download all relevant docs.

...or at least get comfortable googling on your phone. This might eat up a lot of your data plan if you're not on an unlimited account. Ask your client if you can have wifi access on a separate device.

Beyond that, try setting up a test project and disable your internet.

Comment: I do have all that set up already. But I might have to add dependencies / libraries along the way, and you know, things that might pop up in the middle of development.

Comment: It sounds like you should have an honest conversation with your client about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Intranet and have local github/svn servers and then at the end of the day, you merge everything up and do the commit to the real github.
Gradle and everthing else will work offline if you downloaded the necessary files.
But remember, if you really want your files to stay confidential, don't commit it to clouds like github, keep it offline!